# Getting a don't know how to create an ISeq from: clojure.lang.PersistentList$1

Tags: exception, recursion, clojure, lisp

I'm trying to implement [Land of Lisp's Dice of Doom game](http://landoflisp.com/dice_of_doom_v1.lisp) and I'm getting a `Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.PersistentList$1`.

It's occurring when call my `add-new-dice` function:

```
(defn add-new-dice [board player spare-dice]
  (letfn [(f [lst n]
            (cond (empty? lst) nil
                  (zero? n) lst
                  :else (let [current-player (first (first lst))
                              current-dice (first (rest (first  lst)))]
                          (if (and (= current-player player) (< current-dice *max-dice*))
                            (cons (list current-player (+ current-dice 1))
                                  (f (rest lst) (- n 1)))
                            (cons (first lst) (f (rest list) n))))))]
    (f board spare-dice)))
```

with this:

```
(add-new-dice '[(0 1) (1 3) (0 2) (1 1)] 0 2)
```

I'm doing this mostly to familiarize myself with CL code and to get some experience porting it over to Clojure.

If anyone can give me some advice, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Took me a while, but I did get all versions of Dice of Doom working with Clojure (although I used compojure rather than the home rolled web server). Let me know if you want to see how I did things. My code isn't good enough for general release though :(

Comment: Hi Adrian, are you around to chat about it later? I'm having some teething difficulties understanding how to port the CL laziness to lazy-seq :)...

Comment: Hi toofarsideways, best just to e-mail me: I'm adrian.mouat on gmail. Let me know which country/time-zone you're in though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the function `list` instead of your argument `lst` at the second to last line. `(f (rest list) n)` should be `(f (rest lst) n)`

Comment: Thanks Joost, that was a seriously dopey typo on my part. I was frantically wondering what part of this I misunderstood. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, this is a potential problem with clojure being a Lisp-1 (meaning functions and "variables"/arguments all occupy the same name space). If you cannot name your sequence something more useful, it might be better to use the clojure standard lib's naming conventions and use "coll" instead of "lst" for a generic seq'able collection (though personally, I prefer "s" for a plain sequence and "m" for maps)

Comment: For my own edification would someone be willing to explain why a typo replacing a seq with a function produced the exception given? Is clojure.lang.PersistentList the data form of the `list` function?

Comment: I believe that's exactly right Alex, I was treating a function as a list (`(rest list)`)... Joost: Thanks, I think I will!

Comment: @Alex: It's not clojure.lang.PersistentList, it's clojure.lang.PersistentList$1 - which is the class of the clojure.lang.PersistentList/creator function/method thingy.

Comment: @Joost - thanks. Is the class created by the code `public static IFn creator = new RestFn(){ ...` in clojure.lang.PersistentList? And if so why is the class given an arbitrary name rather than reporting the type "clojure.lang.RestFn" (which would be an easier to diagnose error). Is it because RestFn is an abstract class which is then has an anonymously implemented concrete child class?

Comment: @AlexStoddard as far as I understand, it's because creator is an instance of an anonymous class, not a direct instance of RestFn, so it gets an automatically generated class name based on its surrounding class.